# Is there any way to set lotus notes combobox width?

Tags: combobox, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a combobox to show list of information. It is fine when information selected show on view. But when on edit mode, combobox show small width and not show full information.

When on edit mode, it show like below:

[image: combobox]

Is there any way to edit combobox field? Or there any list field that I can use which have a bit wider than combobox? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a Notes client application: 
You can set the width of the combobox in the field properties on the first tab. 
[image: Combobox properties]